# why don't hyperlinks work in word documents

Tags: document-library, document, hyperlink, word

the hyperlinks within the body of my documents in my Document Library don't work (not external hyperlinks to outside sources or in-document links/references) nor do they display the link when you hover over them. This means that end users can't use the link and can't see where the link is supposed to be pointing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: what version of SharePoint are you using and what browsers are you using?

Comment: SharePoint  2013 and I am using Chrome (though I have had reports of this happening with Safari and Firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dealt with this a while ago and found that it is an issue that has no real fix. For me, the hyperlinks worked when I was in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome, so I installed the IETab application (and instructed other end users to install and use it as well). Using that allowed the hyperlinks to work in the Word web app while browsing in Chrome.

Comment: this works well enough. Thanks for giving a definitive answer. Sucks that this is a compatibility issue without a non-workaround solution.